# error php:1054 Notice: Undefined variable: data in C:\xampp\htdocs\awebarts\app\models\Display.php on line 39

Tags: php, mysql, variables, undefined

I have an error Undefined variable return data.

```
<?php
function getData() {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `$this->tablename` ORDER BY `id` DESC";

        if(!$sql = mysql_query($query))
        {
            echo mysql_errno();
        }
        else
        {
            $num = mysql_num_rows($sql);           
            if($num > 0)
            {
                for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++)
                {
                    $data[$i] = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
                }                              
            }
        }        
        return $data;
    }
?>
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: Initialize a `$data = array();` at the begining of your function. Maybe there are no rows, so `$data` wont created.

Answer (score 0):

Define `$data` outside of the `for` loop.

```
function getData() {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `$this->tablename` ORDER BY `id` DESC";
    $data = array();

    if(!$sql = mysql_query($query))
...
```

---

PS: Stop using `mysql_*` functions. Switch to either `MySQLi` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is pretty clear. $data is not initialized properly under specific circumstances:

1. When the if statement "if(!$sql = mysql_query($query))" is true $data is never set
2. When the if statement "if($num > 0)"  is false (aka $num <= 0) $data is never set.

Thus you get a notice that data is undefined as it only gets set if the first if is false and the second if is true.

To correct this and get rid of the message you need to initialize $data at the beginning of the function.